# Javascript - send value and post into lead form

Tags: javascript, html

I have set the URL using the UTM parameters, like below: 
http://www.example.com/tc/example.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=abc

Here is what I placed in the form.

However, if it missed any parts in the URL, it can't get the parameters, how to fix this problem or are there any better way?

Here is the code for getting the UTM parameters

```
document.getElementById('input_url').value = document.URL;

function parseGET(param) {
    var searchStr = document.location.search;
    try {
        var match = searchStr.match('[?&]' + param + '=([^&]+)');
        if (match) {
            var result = match[1];
            result = result.replace(/\+/g, '%20');
            result = decodeURIComponent(result);
            return result;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return '';
    }
}

document.getElementById('utm_source').value = parseGET('utm_source');
document.getElementById('utm_medium').value = parseGET('utm_medium');
document.getElementById('utm_campaign').value = parseGET('utm_campaign');
document.getElementById('utm_term').value = parseGET('utm_term');
document.getElementById('utm_content').value = parseGET('utm_content');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call this function

```
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
        {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }

document.getElementById('utm_source').value=GetQueryStringParams('utm_source');
```